# Why is my scaling (Ctrl-A) causing me problems?

Tags: modeling, mesh, modifiers, mirror

[image]I'm working on a human character and I'm in the middle of modeling.

I have the entire body near complete but I noticed some of my points were off. Like the chest-shoulder region wasn't matching up. I tried to grab with <kbd>G</kbd> but  that ruined the placement of my character hips. So i tried to scale it, same issue.

I decided to move the points to where I needed them the attempted to adjust the hips. Now when I move or scale the hips, my previous points are not set off again. Can someone tell me what my issue is??

I have *Mirror*, *Skin*  and *Subsurf* modifiers added, in that order, but not yet applied.

Comment: It would be good if some screenshots were added, where mesh is shown before and after grabbing. You could also include modifiers' options there

Comment: Hey @MrZak thanks for responding so fast, I tried adding screen shots but the pic always come out pitch black. I'll keep trying, but if you know what the issue for the screen shot i will greatly appreciate your advice.

Comment: And are you *scaling* the mesh / its parts with `S` ? Or *apply* scale with `Ctrl`+`A` ?

Comment: I've tried both and the result is the same.

Comment: If images aren't working for you, try [pasteall](http://www.pasteall.org/) for images or blend files.

Comment: I know how to add the image, its taking the screen shot thats causing me problems.

Comment: Mac or Windows?

Comment: Try using Snipping Tool for windows or command F4 for mac

Comment: Fixed the screen shot issue!. Now you see in the image, after fixing the chest, the left side of the hip is slightly off

Comment: Try pressing 'o' to turn off proportional editing.

Comment: Never mind false alarm.. smh thanks for trying to help everyone

Comment: If the question has been solved than please add an answer with description what the problem was and what did you do.

Comment: I haven't figured it out yet, but when I do, I'll post the problem and a way to solve it here.